# Error en Jquery Datatable al hacer scroll vertical

Tags: datatables, scroll

Tengo una tabla que esconde y enseña columnas dependiendo de un parámetro que le paso, todo va bien hasta que implemento el scroll vertical y me el siguiente error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined.EN otras funciones que no escondo la columna, no recibo errores He intentado hacer un ejemplo demostrable pero no he sabido, estoy intentando hacerlo.

```
function busProyectosNtactil() {

    if ($("#chkOf").prop('checked')) {
        interruptor = '1';
    } else {
        interruptor = '0';
    }

    if ($("#prsp").prop('checked')) {
        prsp = '1';
    } else {
        prsp = '0';
    }


    var parametros = {
        "interruptor": interruptor,
        "prsp": prsp
    };


    tblProyectosNtactil = $('#tbl_ProyectosTactil').DataTable({
        scrollY: '35vh',
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "scrollX": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "searching": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,

         "destroy": "true",
            "ajax": {
                "data": parametros,
                "url": "php/tos.php",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataSrc": "",
            },


            "columns": [ {
                    "data": "id"
                }, {
                    "data": "prio" ,"responsivePriority": "9"
                }, {
                    "data": "eje"
                },{
                    "data": "cta_id"
                },{
                    "data": 'emp',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        emp = devuelveEmpresa(data)
                            return  emp;
                    }
                },{
                    "data": "nombre_seguimiento" ,"responsivePriority": "8"
                }, {
                    "data": "name" ,"responsivePriority": "3"
                }, {
                    "data": "dsc"
                }, {
                    "data": "nombre_director"
                }, {
                    "data": "nombre_responsable"
                }, {
                    "data": "nombre_grupo"
                }, {
                    "data": "prsp_acu_tot" ,"responsivePriority": "4"
                },{
                    "data": "prsp_sol" 
                },{
                    "data": "fch_fin_prevista" ,"responsivePriority": "5"
                }, ],
        });

        //Esto es lo que me provoca el error.
        if(prsp==1){
            tblProyectosNtactil.columns( [0,1,5,8,10,11,13] ).visible( false );
            tblProyectosNtactil.columns( [2,3,4] ).visible( true );
        }
        else if(prsp==0)
        {
            tblProyectosNtactil.columns( [1,5,8,10,11,13] ).visible( true );
            tblProyectosNtactil.columns( [0,2,3,4] ).visible( false );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Prueba si scrollY deberia ir entre comillas

Comment: Acabo de probar y sigue el mismo error.